# Native C++ cross platform interaction with a database

Tags: c++, database, cross-platform

I'm not planning on using a Microsoft Access database in the long run, but using it as an example, what are my options for having a database (locally and not) that I can retrieve and send data to from a native C++ program? Currently I am restricted to Microsoft Access with `ODBC` which requires `#include <windows.h>`. I am planning on having my code run on both `Windows`, `Mac` and `Linux`, but I can't find something cross platform as such. In practicality for my code, I would just want to represent a portion of a table's field as a `std::vector` and then work with a native C++ datatype such as `std::string` for each of the rows in a database.

Comment: C++ doesn't include any standard functions or classes for database access.  You'll need to use a library of some kind, and they're all different.

Comment: Is there something that is cross platform?

Comment: I suspect there's nothing cross *database*, much less cross platform.  But I have to admit I don't know.

Comment: See Qt cross-platform framework https://www.qt.io/product/framework